What to do with guessed answers?
What, if anything, should be done with guessed answers?
I mean answers starting with phrases like: "I am not sure if I understood completely the question" or "If I understand your question correctly".
Those answers appear to attempt to answer something that may not be completely clear to the answerer.

If they are good and useful, then edit them and remove the unhelpful and distract text. If not, if they are little more than wild guesses, then down-vote them. The site is for questions that are, in fact, answerable, along with definitive answers to the questions.

@HovercraftFullOfEels: But I do not like to be an editor of those answers. I have a real job, which asks more then enough time.... So unfortunately I will leave them untouched, deteriorating the quality of stackoverflow.com

Regarding, "But I do not like to be an editor of those answers. I have a real job...", You asked what to do with these answers, suggesting that you want to do something. If in reality you don't want to do this, then honestly, why ask at all?

I have a comment that I usually paste under stuff like this (and it's usually the extent of my interaction with the post, because I usually am not an SME in the area): "note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer]."

Handle as per usual because there is nothing special about such answers. But afterwards do take a good look at the question it is under because if it attracts that kind of answer... it probably is written to invite them.

Downvote them if they are wrong.
Edit the answer and remove the preamble if the answer is correct or at least seems to be correct.
A lot of the time, it means the question has issues, so you should check if the question needs to be closed.

A great deal of answers I find have useless preambles, but the core information given is useful, thus no need to intervene.
Personally (if I can), I try to improve such answers to cut out any noise/make them more straight to the point.
If an answerer did misunderstand the question, one should leave a comment pointing that out. In that case, editing would change the post from the writer's intent.
